# Send error response from pre filter directly from Spring Gateway

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using Spring Gateway with Spring WebFlux application. In my case I need to return HTTP `417` error if certain criteria is not met before calling any service downstream. For some reason it is not returning the error; in fact it is not returning anything.. request is just hanging. This is my code.

```
@Component
public class GlobalGatewayPreFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<GlobalGatewayPreFilter.Config> {

    public GlobalGatewayPreFilter() {
        super(Config.class);
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> exchange
                .getPrincipal()
                .filter(principal -> principal instanceof UserAuthenticationToken)
                .cast(UserAuthenticationToken.class)
                .filter(token -> (token.getUser().isVerified()))
                .defaultIfEmpty(setErrorResponse(exchange)).flatMap(chain::filter);
    }

    private ServerWebExchange setErrorResponse(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED);
        exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
        return exchange;
    }

    public static class Config {
        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I was able to solve this solve by using following. I am posting here with a hope that some would benefit from it.

```
@Component
public class GlobalGatewayPreFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<GlobalGatewayPreFilter.Config> {

    public GlobalGatewayPreFilter() {
        super(Config.class);
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> exchange
                .getPrincipal()
                .filter(principal -> principal instanceof UserAuthenticationToken)
                .cast(UserAuthenticationToken.class)
                .filter(token -> (token.getUser().isVerified()))
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> setErrorResponse(exchange.getResponse()).setComplete().then(Mono.empty())))
                .flatMap(chain::filter);
    }

    private ServerHttpResponse setErrorResponse(ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse) {
        serverHttpResponse.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED);
        return serverHttpResponse;
    }

    public static class Config {
        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please provide some comments on each part of your code to explain what's is being achieved in each step?